# How to align center while having an expanding size policy?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am following a bunch of guides I managed to come close to what I expect for my program to look. However with the solution I came to the button is added at the top-left corner of the main layout (`layout_main`), while I'd like it to be centered. This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QSizePolicy,
    QTabWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    qApp,
)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1000, 700)
        
        btn_start = QPushButton("Test button", self)
        btn_start.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        btn_start.setMaximumSize(900, 500)
        btn_start.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        
        lbl_test = QLabel("Test label", self)
        
        layout_main = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_main.addWidget(btn_start)
        #layout_main.setAlignment(btn_start, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout_main.addWidget(lbl_test)
        
        tabs = QTabWidget(self)
        tabs.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.North)
        tabs.setMovable(True)

        main = QWidget(self)
        main.setLayout(layout_main)
        
        tabs.addTab(main, "Main tab")
        
        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is how it looks

[image]

When I tried to center it with `layout_main.setAlignment(btn_start, Qt.AlignCenter)`, the commented line, then the button is centered, but sized down to the minimum size

[image]

How can I center the button while having it expand the way I want? I have tried lots of things like adding the button to it's own layout or inside a container widget, but no solution worked yet.

Comment: Is the maximum size a requirement?

Comment: Use a grid-layout instead of a vbox-layout. Then do `layout_main.addWidget(btn_start, 0, 1)` and `layout_main.addWidget(lbl_test, 1, 0, 1, 3)`. This will create a 2x3 grid, with the button in the top centre column and the label spanning the bottom three columns. The expanding size-policy should ensure the button assumes its maximum size (when possible).

Comment: That worked perfectly! Feel free to post as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code and find out that the `btn_start.setMaximumSize` limit the button to expand.
Edit your code as I told you now, if there are other problems comment and I will edit the solution.